# How to set dict as json object using redis-py?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, redis, redis-py

As of `redis-py` `4.0`, json is supported.  I am using `redis-py` version `4.0.2` on `Windows 11`.  I have a redis server running in docker utilizing `redislabs/rejson:latest`.

I am attempting to load a json object via the following -

```
import redis
from redis.commands.json.path import Path
from redis import exceptions
from redis.commands.json.decoders import unstring, decode_list

r = redis.Redis()
d = {"hello": "world", b"some": "value"}
r.json().set("somekey", Path.rootPath(), d)
```

Just how it is done in the tests - https://github.com/redis/redis-py/blob/e8bcdcb97b8c915e2bb52353aeda17c00e1be215/tests/test_json.py#L19

However I am getting this error -

```
TypeError: keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not bytes
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a b prefix in your json, which stands for bytes.

Just remove `'b'` from `b"some":` and it would work as expected:

```
d = {"hello": "world", "some": "value"}
```

Comment: Thanks! Interesting enough, they use that in the testcase https://github.com/redis/redis-py/blob/e8bcdcb97b8c915e2bb52353aeda17c00e1be215/tests/test_json.py#L17

Answer (score 0):

This will fix it (adding `decode_keys=True` to decode any binary keys):

```
r.json().set("somekey", Path.rootPath(), d, decode_keys=True)
```